# Is there a difference between $x=0$ and $0=x$

Tags: real-analysis, logic, soft-question

Is there a  difference between $x=2$ and $2=x$

One of my students asked this question .

What would be a good answer for this ?

Here $x$ is unknown. After calculating we get $x=2$

Comment: Equality is symmetric, so if $a = b$ then $b = a$. The statements are different, but logically equivalent.

Comment: An equivalence relation is one that operates the same in both directions (better ways of saying this).  In computer programming languages, there is a difference in what is communicated to the computer, but in mathematics these are equivalent.

Comment: It depends on what you mean. As strings, clearly they are different. From the perspective of equality of numbers, they have the same meaning because of symmetry.

Comment: when write a proof, x = 2 means assignment. We assign 2 to a variable x. But $2 = x$  is a just equality check.

Comment: There are also specific contexts in math where we use an equal sign asymmetrically, for instance sigma notation where the variable on the left is customarily the index of summation.

Comment: "when write a proof, x = 2 means assignment"  Not, really.  It can also be a deduced result.  If x + 2 = 0 then x = -2.  That's not an assignment; it's a conclusion.  x = 2 and 2 = x both mean exactly the same thing-- that x and 2 are equal values.  As to *why* one would say this... well, it's the difference between "The man who lives at 22B Baker street is Sherlock Holmes" and "Sherlock Holmes is the man who lives at 22B Baker street".  Are those mean the same thing or not?

Comment: Mathematically, no, but I was really surprised when I learned that for some students there's a *huge* psychological difference, to the point that $2x+ 3 = y$ looks like something completely new and mysterious, after seeing only "$y$ on the left" linear equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They both have the same meaning.

It's typically more common however to write the 'quantity of interest' or 'quantity being defined' on the left hand side. So $x=2$ is more common in texts if you are defining $x$ to be equal to $2$.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference at all. It is more common and 'classic' to write it like $x=2$ with variable/constant/function on the left, and value on the right.

**Side note:** Also, if $x=0$, then interestingly $0$ is a value of both $x$ and $-x$. If a function is equal to $0$, then the opposite, **not inversion** of the function is also $0$.